# How to update data in shiny app periodically?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have deployed shiny server with several shiny apps. Each app is used as online dashboard which should be refreshed periodically (e.g. every 2 hours or at 10pm every day) according to my plan.

Now the server code for each application looks like

```
## server.R

data<-sqlQuery(...)

shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
...
renderPlotly()
}
```

The main goal is to refresh the *global data* which is loaded using SQL every time the server starts without restarting the server itself. I'm not interested in reactive solutions which use reactivePoll or invalidateLater due to the fact that this approach will lead to a multiple queries each time the user refresh the page in browser.

Actually, I'm a bit confused that Shiny doesn't provide any native implementation of such feature. Are there any great workarounds to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Step one is to get yourself an auto-scheduler. I use `taskscheduleR` because I can't for the life of me figure out windows scheduler, and also the `later` package for some other tricky things.

Then you need to schedule your SQL download, and save that SQL as an R image.

Finally, just use `deployApp("...", launch.browser = F, forceUpdate = T)`

### My Workflow

```
library(later)

shiny.auto <- function(interval = 2*60*60){ # 2 hours 60 minutes 60 seconds
     source("script source1")
     source("shinyappscript")
     later::later(shiny.auto, interval)
}
```

Script source1:

```
data<-sqlQuery(...)
save.image(...)
```

shinyappscript:

```
load(...)
deployApp("...", launch.browser = F, forceUpdate = T)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: How do you stop the later function from  running :D

Comment: Terminate the R session :D

Comment: Slightly confused, where do you use the taskScheduleR package? Do you use it to periodically run the first bit of code?

Comment: You can use taskScheduleR if you want it to run at a certain time. I only answered the "run every two hours" portion.